# JazzCash Gateway V2 PHP Integration

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I am trying to integrate JazzCash Gateway V2, and want to make a Direct Pay transaction which is defined by the [documentation](https://sandbox.jazzcash.com.pk/SandboxDocumentation/v4.2/ApiReferences.html#in) as "This is a single transaction to authorize payment and transfer funds from payer's account to merchant’s account."

Following is my hash function

```
function get_SecureHash($data_array) {
    ksort($data_array);
    $str = '';
    foreach($data_array as $key => $value) {
        if(!empty($value)) {
            $str = $str . '&' . $value;
        }
    }
    $str = $saltkey.$str;
    $pp_SecureHash = hash_hmac('sha256', $str, $saltkey);
    return $pp_SecureHash;
}
```

I have matched my hash and it same as the one calculated by HashCalculator recommended by the documentation. https://github.com/aliabidzaidi/HashCalculator

I am using following url:

```
$post_url = "https://sandbox.jazzcash.com.pk/ApplicationAPI/API/Purchase/PAY";
```

My array looks as follows:

```
$data_array = array(
   "pp_IsRegisteredCustomer"=> "yes",
   "pp_ShouldTokenizeCardNumber"=> "yes",
   "pp_CustomerID"=> "25352",
   "pp_CustomerEmail"=> "abc@abc.com",
   "pp_CustomerMobile"=> "03331234567",
   "pp_Version"=> "2.0",
   "pp_TxnType"=> "MPAY",
   "pp_TxnRefNo"=> "T".date('YmdHisu'),
   "pp_MerchantID"=> "MYMERCHANTID",
   "pp_Password"=> "MYPASSWORD",
   "pp_Amount"=> "20000",
   "pp_TxnCurrency"=> "PKR",
   "pp_TxnDateTime"=> date('YmdHis'),
   "pp_TxnExpiryDateTime"=> date('YmdHis',strtotime("+1 hours")),
   "pp_BillReference"=> "billRef",
   "pp_Description"=> "Description of transaction",
   "pp_CustomerCardNumber"=> "512345000000008",
   "pp_CustomerCardCVV"=> "100",
   "pp_CustomerCardExpiry"=> "01/39",
   "pp_SecureHash"=> "",
   "pp_DiscountedAmount"=> "",
   "pp_DiscountBank"=> "",
   "pp_UsageMode"=> "API"
);
```

When I run the curl, I get following output:

```
{"responseCode":"110","responseMessage":"Please provide a valid value for pp_ Txn Ref No.","status":null,"pp_RetreivalReferenceNo":null,"secureHash":"9DE9F8E571F29CBD1316DFB2F0388E3FBE1CA9BC26FB9C284DF900DCCBA0C301"}
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because the date format for pp_TxnDateTime and pp_TxnRefNo is change
In your array , `"pp_TxnRefNo"=> "T".date('YmdHisu')`
and `"pp_TxnDateTime"=> date('YmdHis')`

Make sure that the format is the same, therefore, change the following:

`"pp_TxnRefNo"=> "T".date('YmdHisu')`
into  `"pp_TxnRefNo"=> "T".date('YmdHis')`

I hope it will work.

Comment: thank you for your response. I made change to the code as you suggested. After that I got error that 2.0 version doesn't have MPAY TxnType so I changed version to 1.1 and I am back to similar error:
"responseCode":"110","responseMessage":"Please provide a valid value for pp_TxnRefNo/pp_Amount."

Comment: do you still want help or have u resolved ur issue?

Comment: yes still need help. Issue still pending

Comment: hmmm, you need to provide complete information regarding your issue in order to get apropriate solution ,
But still i can make some suggestions, 
1. make sure you fetch amount from database and explode '.' from amount .

Comment: There is no database involved. This is all hard coded. Once this works than I will move to dynamic values. The issue is like I said in my comment above, it is giving error of "responseCode":"110","responseMessage":"Please provide a valid value for pp_TxnRefNo/pp_Amount." Can you share a hard coded example which is working for you? Thanks